# Why does user jenkins throw an error when running capistrano script from within the Jenkins interface but user root from command line does not?

Tags: jenkins, capistrano

I am very new to Jenkins and Capistrano. I've found existing documentation to be very fragmented when it comes to running Capistrano from within Jenkins. Having said that, I have successfully installed Jenkins and Capistrano. I've created the items and can trigger the scripts. For my initial test I am just running the default deployment script as it is out of the box.

When I run the following via Jenkins trigger:

```
#!/bin/bash -exl

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
cap staging deploy
```

I get the error (edited for brevity):

```
+ USER=jenkins
+ LOGNAME=jenkins

Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.

*Nothing in /capistrano.log
```

When I run the same commands inside of a script from the command line I get:

```
+ USER=root
+ LOGNAME=root

*capistrano.log file:
---
  INFO START 2016-09-29 16:50:03 +0000 cap staging deploy
  INFO ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
```

It appears that the jenkins user is not configured correctly and is missing some dependencies but I can't find how to fix this.

Help is appreciated. If anyone knows of a good resource for using Capistrano together with Jenkins that would also be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was a space in my workspace directory name. The directory name was not being interpreted correctly within the Jenkins script for some reason, but was fine in the bash script I ran from the command line. Thanks to my buddy Scott for figuring that one out!